# How refresh data in EJBs on Database change?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, entitymanager

I am working with EJB 1.1 and would like to get the updated data in the app when ever there is database change. Currently it takes random amount of time to get the updated data. I am not sure what i am supposed to be looking for . Is there a config option in App or Jboss server that the app is residing on?

I found the option `<clean-read-ahead-on-load>True</clean-read-ahead-on-load>`

but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

update: I found several posts showing how to invalidate ejb cache when using JPA if the data on the database changed asynchronously ( changed manually outside the app). but i am still looking for a way to do it in EJB 1.1

one example is

```
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll()
```

but how do i get access to entityManager in the first place?

Update 2: if there is no way to do it just with EJBs to actively look for data change can i just manually invalidate the cache from the app side? i.e., when i know that the data must have changed asynchronously  i want to do something manually on the app side to invalidate the cache.

Comment: I think it is not possible only with ejbs. You can use hibernate, you should enable second level cache. When database change occurred hibernate will track this change and it will update the objects BUT the change must be made from your application, because there is no way for hibernate to track changes that are made directly to the database via some console.

Comment: I don't use Hibernate in my app. Is there another solution i can implement? Is there any server configuration i can look in to?